# Take items from list one by one without losing the old value

Tags: c#, arraylist

I need to make an api call by sending a list

```
List<string> fieldDurations = new List<string>
{"4h", "12h", "16h", "1d", "2d", "3d", "4d", "5d", "6d", "7d"};
```

I do not want to send the entire list at the same time or one by one, i need to increment it (old value + new value).
Something like:

```
Call 1: var test =feasiApiV1TestFeasiPostWithHttpInfo(fieldDurations) should have "4h"
call 2: var test =feasiApiV1TestFeasiPostWithHttpInfo(fieldDurations) should have "4h", "12h"
call 3: var test =feasiApiV1TestFeasiPostWithHttpInfo(fieldDurations) should have "4h", "12h", "16h"
```

and so on. Any ideas how i can do that?

Comment: Can you explain what `var test = feasiApiV1TestFeasiPostWithHttpInfo(fieldDurations)` does, and how that relates to `fieldDurations`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate through the List in a `for` loop and always use LINQ to take the amount of elements you want, like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= fieldDurations.Count; i++)
{
    fieldDurations.Take(i);
}
```

This iterates over the Count of the array and takes `i` amount of Elements starting at the first one. `i` starts at `1` instead of `0` because `Take(0)` is useless

**Edit:** Thanks to [Kyle Polansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785174/kyle-polansky) in the comments for pointing out the loop condition should be `i <= fieldDurations.Count`

Comment: If you dont want to go for LINQ , you may also use GetRange , Its much more efficient to use than Take

Comment: @VishalSharma I never understood people not wanting to use LINQ, is there a good reason in a certain case not to use it?

Comment: Since the for loop is 1-indexed, shouldn't the conditional be `i <= fieldDurations.Count` to include the last item in the list?

Comment: @MindSwipe , Performance is lost in this perticular case. check here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32691284/1018054